# How long does it take to write to document.cookie

Tags: javascript, mobile, cookies

Was wondering how long it takes to write to document.cookie. Ran into an edge case when setting a cookie and re-directing to another page and the document.cookie was not getting set. Seemed to have different performance on a desktop (Chrome, firefox) vs iphone/tablet (safari)

Seemed to worked correctly in all cases when I added a set timeout of about 500ms

// writing cookie out

```
   function set_cookie(name, value ) {
        var date =  new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); 
        var cookie = name + "=" + value + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString() + ";";
        document.cookie = cookie;

    }
```

// reading cookie

```
function read_Cookie(name) {

        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
                var cVal = c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
                return cVal;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

// button click setting cookie and navigation

```
        $("#goToWebButton").click(function() {
             if ($('#chkDontShow').attr('checked') == 'checked') {
                set_cookie('IgnoreInAppLink','web');
               }
            setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = '';}, 500);
        });

        $("#goToAppButton").click(function() {
          if ($('#chkDontShow').attr('checked') == 'checked') {
                set_cookie('IgnoreInAppLink','app');
            }
            setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = '';},500);

        });
```

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript is by it's very nature single-threaded therefore the redirect shouldn't be executed until the cookie has been written regardless of how long it takes (almost instantaneous). That said, as pointed out at [Is JavaScript guaranteed to be single-threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734025/is-javascript-guaranteed-to-be-single-threaded) that may not always be the case. To mitigate this you might consider using jQuery's deferred object as such:

```
function set_cookie(name,value,deferred) { // added deferred argument
    var date =  new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); 
    var cookie = name + "=" + value + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString() + ";";
    document.cookie = cookie;
    deferred.resolve();
}

var deferred = $.Deferred();

deferred.done(function() {
    window.location.href = "";
});

$("#goToAppButton").click(function() {
    if ($("#chkDontShow").attr("checked") == "checked") {
        set_cookie("IgnoreInAppLink","web",deferred);
    } else {
        deferred.resolve();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your usage of `$.Deferred` does not improve anything over OP's code without the timeout. That aside, a function should never take a deferred as an argument, but rather return a promise.